Why doesn't Google's search bar have a focus ring?
I'm working on web accessibility from a web publishing perspective, and WCAG requires most sites to show a focus ring on control elements, input formatting, etc. that the user can interact with.
However, Google doesn't seem to offer a focus ring style for the search bar.
Q. Isn't this a violation of WCAG?
Q. If it is not against WCAG, what is the rationale behind it?
Your answer will be a great asset to me.
Thank you in advance.

As a private company, Google has no obligation to conform to legislation on accessibility. At least in Europe. But that is not the point.
Not showing focus on elements that could receive focus is, as you said, is a violation of WCAG, especially the success criterion 2.4.7 Focus Visible. But the success criterion doesn't require a focus ring necessarily, it only states:

Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible.

And if look more closely at the success criterion, it gives the following example:

When text fields receive focus, a vertical bar is displayed in the field, indicating that the user can insert text[.]

This is just how Google's search bar shows the focus.
Yes, it could be more beneficial to users with visual disabilities to better discern the focus but that is not required by WCAG.

Thank you for your well-reasoned and detailed response.
As you say, the Focus Visible (Level AA) section does not specify what the focus should look like, but the Focus Appearance (Level AAA) section is more detailed about how to display the focus.
The example for Focus Appearance (Level AAA) says: ‘When text fields receive focus, an outline is displayed around the field, indicating that the input has focus.’ This is a juxtaposition of the two. Focus Visible (Level AA) and Focus Appearance (Level AAA) seem to be contradictory examples.

In my personal opinion, Focus Appearance (Level AAA) is a higher level than Focus Visible (Level AA), so for someone like me who needs to improve accessibility properly, following the higher-level guidance is a safe choice.
Anyway, thanks for your comment as it gave me the opportunity to learn more about the guidelines.
Focus Appearance (Level AAA)

By complying with 2.4.7 you are already "improving accessibility properly".
While you can make the argument, that "more is better", it's not always so for accessibilty. And following level AAA is only recommended practice, if you have a specific need to do so.
To understand the levels correctly, you can think of Level A as the "essential" level, Level AA as the "sufficient" level and Level AAA as the "optional" level.

There's no contradiction between 2.4.7 and 2.4.13: 2.4.7 requires "... a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible". 2.4.13 says: "When the keyboard focus indicator is visible ..."
None of the criteria requires you to use a focus ring, btw. It's only one of many ways to indicate keyboard focus. But if you implement 2.4.13, the indicator must adhere to specific measurements.
If you like to implement af focus ring, consider using a two-colored ring:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/css/C40.html
